# How to make custom attribute comparable(script)

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

```
Code in my Setup.php

'compare_field_freegift' => 
array (
'group' => 'Gift Product',
'label' => 'Gift Inside',
'type'  => 'int',
'note'  => 'Comparing product field(Yes/No)',
'input' => 'boolean',
'global'=> Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
'visible' => 1,
'required' => 1,
'user_defined' => 0,
'searchable' => 0,
'filterable' => 0,
'comparable' => 1,//Comparable on Front-end
'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,downloadable',
'visible_on_front'  => 1,
'visible_in_advanced_search' => 0,
'unique' => 0
)
```

All things are working fine except making field 'comparable'->True.
I tried with 'true','1' and 1 also but it is not coming.